# Is there a way to track pre-merged and post-merged code review for a branch in Atlassian Crucible

Tags: git, github, merge, atlassian-crucible

Our team has recently migrated to Atlassian Crucible for our peer reviews. The workflow we currently have in place is

- Create Feature branch off of develop
- Once the branch is wrapped up push the branch to origin and create a code review in crucible for the branch commit
- Once the code review process is complete, close the code review and merge the feature branch back to develop and push the latest develop to origin.

The issue we are facing with this particular workflow is that once i have merged the branch back to develop and pushed it to origin crucible reports show these changes to develop as changes which have gone in without any reviews. So somehow these changes are not being traced back to code review we had on the feature branch. I am almost certain we are missing something in our workflow and would love to hear from the experts and rectify that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you explain this in more detail please?  When you refer to Crucible reports do you mean review coverage report, http://FISHEYE_URL/plugins/servlet/review-coverage/REPO_NAME?
What commits are marked as unreviewed, just the merge commits, or the actual commits made on the feature branch?
In the former case this is the issue: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CRUC-6701 you may want to vote on and watch to get notified when that's resolved.
In the latter case, does it happen because someone perhaps rebased commits from the feature branch when merging them into the development branch?  Crucible at the moment won't detect follow up rebased commits I'm afraid.  Instead those would be processed as unreviewed brand new commits.
Hope that helps, let me know if you have further questions.
Kind regards,

Comment: Hi Swiety, Thanks for your answer. when i refer to Crucible reports, I do mean the review coverage report. Also Only the merge commits are marked as un-reviewed which would mean we need to wait for the Jira issue you mentioned to get it resolved. Do let us know if you have any suggestions/temporary change of workflow to get around this issue. Really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Do vote please on the CRUC-6701 issue to increase the chance it gets fixed sooner rather than later.  Can't think of a temporary workaround I'm afraid.   You could try adding to artificial reviews but this seems a very ugly workaround.